# Create a new variable which indicates whether a house was recently built vs. not

Tags: r, statistics

I need to answer this question:

"Use the variable which indicates when a house was built (yr_built) to create a new variable which indicates whether a house was recently built vs. not. A house is considered recently built if it was built after the year 2000."

I have tried using the mutate function in a number of ways, but I haven't been able to make it work. Any ideas of the code I should use? Thank you.

Comment: we need a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you

Answer (score 0):

It would be great, if you provided some example data...

But using `dplyr` something like

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
   mutate(built_recently = yr_built > 2000)
```

should be sufficient

Comment: Thanks a lot, certain small things that are vital are sometimes skimmed over in class